# Some keys on my laptop's keyboard stops working after i login in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on my samsung R480 laptop.Now the problem is that i can't use some keys on my laptop's keyboard such as 'u','i','o','p','j','k','l',';''m','.' and also when pressing the keys shows different behaviors such as right clicking, or moving the pointer, or inserting spaces etc. Any way to solve the problem ?

Comment: If you found the solution, please post in answer box, it helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu 11.10 , Ubuntu 3D desktop
Press your <kbd>Super</kbd> key once
[image: http://assets.lifehack.org/wp-content/files/2007/05/20070529-windowskey-f1.jpg]

Type Keyboard 
Then Layout setting ( blue underlined )
Reset to Defult

Hope this helps

Comment: figured out the problem...thanks anyway for the suggestion...:)

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is that is none that's just some sort of serious bugs got on 11.10 version it's deficient on some kernel core so kindly use any Ubuntu LTS (long term support) like Ubuntu 10.04 or upgrade to 12.04 even though in 12.04(precise pangolin)several crucial errors like net connection ,Wi-Fi, graphics kernels are missing out but even though 10.04 is older it works flawless with every kernels try it :)

Comment: figured out the problem...thanks anyway for the suggestions...:)

Answer (score 0):

Your <kbd>Fn</kbd> key was stuck down.  On a *Samsung R480*, and most other laptops without a separate numberpad, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + those keys act as either <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Ins</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, or the arrow keys, if <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is off.